Google play rejected my app saying issue found: stability issues. How to debug or fix?
I was pushing an update to playstore suddenly my app got rejected after review. The update is about a small value tweak.
I don't know what is wrong but it gives me rejection now and the rejection message is too generalize that I cannot determine from where the issue is coming from. Can anyone help me on that.
This is the message what they gave:

Issue found: App stability
We experienced stability issues with your app during testing and were unable to evaluate it for policy compliance. It’s critical that your app behaves predictably at run time and doesn’t crash, hang, or display error messages.

Issue details
We found an issue in the following area(s):
Version code 16
To bring your app into compliance, follow these steps:
To resolve this issue, make sure your app behaves predictably at run time and doesn’t crash, hang, or display error messages.
About the Families Policy Requirements
If one of the target audiences for your app is children, you must comply with the Families Policy Requirements.
How can I debug???

"The update is about a small value tweak." can you add more details about what you have changed

Firebase Crashlytics sounds like a nice solution to check what is happening.
